# ¿como obtener penúltimo registro en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Quiero obtener el penúltimo registro insertado de un usuario especifico en MYSQL, y una ves que se obtiene debo de sumarlo un día :

Ejemplo: si penúltimo registro es 2017-06-30 debería de sumarlo un día mas osea 2017-07-01

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en la imagen tengo 2018-06-30 entonces debe de agregar un día más.

Estoy usando MySQL.

Comment: Probaste algo hasta ahora? recuerda que siempre tenes que poner que probaste.

Comment: estas trabajando las tablas con llaves primarias como un id? o solo esos dos campos?

Comment: Son con llaves primarias y utilizo inner join `SELECT t.idTraba, t.nomTraba, p.fechaBoleta FROM planilla p INNER JOIN trabajador t ON p.idTraba = t.idTraba WHERE t.idTraba = 2`

Comment: Tu tabla la cual tiene el campo "fechaBoleta" tiene un indice para identificar cual registro vas a sumarle un día?

Comment: no solo lo estuve haciendo con el identificador del trabajado que seria el Id

Comment: Por favor, pulsa sobre [edit] y agrega toda la informacion que se te pide en la pregunta, no como comentario. Ademas, eso no es un intento, ahi solo uniste las tablas.. no probaste ni un group by?

Comment: Se me ocurre una posible solución, sin embargo sin un campo id único en tu tabla planilla se me hace un tanto complicado al momento de hacer la suma del dia al registo

Comment: En ese caso debo de agregar un campo como identificador ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer utilizando ordenamiento y paginado a la misma vez, o sea, la idea es, ordenas por el campo **fechaBoleta** dices que el pageSize sea de 1 elemento y muestras la pagina número 2, la consulta sería algo como esto:

```
SELECT * FROM tuTabla
ORDER BY fechaBoleta DESC
LIMIT 1, 1
```

De esta forma obtienes el penultimo elemento de la tabla.